# Uninstalled Kubernetes but I keep getting: "unable to resolve host slave-node"

Tags: 16.04, cluster, kubernetes

I recently installed Kubernetes with helm and tried to setup a cluster on my Ubuntu 16.04 unity, I setup 1 master node and 1 slave node.

I removed everything related to Kubernetes, but everytime I run a command in terminal, I keep getting this error message

```
 unable to resolve host slave-node
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the hostname is different from the host name, you should modify the name in the following path /etc/hosts

Comment: so Kubernetes modifies this file?

Comment: It is not a configuration that you must do to the static IP to modify the nodes, after having modified it I recommend you restart the server or the service

Comment: It's `/etc/hostname`

Answer (score 1):

I accepted the answer above because it's almost correct

`/etc/hosts` is correct, Kubernetes modified `/etc/hostname` I had to fix that.

How did I know? I just found out after months of having this problem, I found out that chrome started calling my ubuntu pc profile `slave-node`. I wanted to know what defines the PC name, it's either `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/hostname`, the first one isn't the problem so it turned out to be the second.